# AJAX issue with Apache .htaccess file

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I have removed the hashbang from the URL with the below code. But for an AJAX it is loading the index.html. How can I fix?

I have added `<base href="/">` in `index.html` and `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in AngularJS controller.

Here's my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```